# How to paste values in multiple excel worksheets using VBA macros

Tags: excel, vba

```
Workbooks("Oct_2022.xlsm").Worksheets("Marketing").Range("E:E").Copy Workbooks("test.xlsx").Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Range("A:A")
```

I have used the above code to copy values from a worksheet named "Marketing" and paste the values into multiple workSheets. But somehow my code doesn't works. Kindly suggest a method to paste values into multiple worksheets at a time

Comment: Please show us your code "what does not work". The code above is not the correct code as you tell us multiple worksheets. The code above copies only to one worksheet.

Comment: I used array method method to paste the values in two worksheets named sheet 1 and sheet 2. That is not working

Comment: Please show us your code "what does not work". The code above is not the correct code as you tell us multiple worksheets. The code above copies only to one worksheet.

Comment: Please read [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [mre]

Comment: @Aldert , The OP is a new member, and his question is clear, actually I don't know why his question got closed

Comment: @Tom Brunberg ,The OP is a new member, and his question is clear, actually I don't know why his question got closed

Comment: @Waleed I would not call a phrase "But somehow my code doesn't works" a clear description of a problem. Therefore, I asked OP to read the help pages I referred to. As I was waiting for an edit, I did not participate in closing the question.

Comment: @Waleed, I did not close the question either.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible. You cannot avoid an iteration between the array sheets. Please, try the next way. It does  not use clipboard (not copying format, too):

```
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  For Each ws In Worksheets(Array("db", "Report"))
        ws.Range("A:A").Value = Workbooks("Oct_2022.xlsm").Worksheets("Marketing").Range("E:E")
  Next
```